# How do I open multiple files from lf file manager?

Tags: file-management

I use the **space** key to select multiple files but then when I do `:open` it only opens one of then (despite multiple being selected). I find it strange because the **space** key seems to work fine for other operations like copying and pasting multiple files.
I took a look at [their documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gokcehan/lf) but haven't found anything specific to this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create custom `open` command and supply multiple arguments with `$fx` instead of a single argument with `$f`.

`$f`: Current file selection as a full path.

`$fx`: Selected file(s) (i.e. 'fs') if there are any selected files, otherwise current file selection (i.e. 'f').

See [Opening Files](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gokcehan/lf#hdr-Opening_Files) documentation.

Comment: I tweaked my `lfrc` with the following code:```cmd open ${{
    test -L $f && f=$(readlink -f $f)
    case $(file --mime-type $f -b) in
        text/*) geany $fx;;
        *) for f in $fx; do xdg-open $f > /dev/null 2> /dev/null & done;;
    esac
}}``` I copied and pasted it from the documentation link that you have provided - **it works**. It remains unclear to me why simpler one-liners from this documentation do not work. Either `cmd open &xdg-open $fx` and `cmd open &$OPENER $fx` do nothing. When open is defined with `cmd open xdg-open $fx` lf outputs:`#command not found: xdg-open`